# Are sins = crime in ancient Jews?

Tags: sin, judaism

Ancient Judaism is religious society. Religious society, unlike secular society, has a feature. What's prohibited by their religions are also prohibited by laws.

A lot like Muslim society right now.

So religious laws tend to be the law of the land. Now we have crimes that's not sin, like money laundering or gambling online. We also have sins that's not a crime, like fornication, and porn.

What about in Ancient Jews? Do crimes and sins always coincide?

The reason why this question is relevant to christianity is because 
questions like is it a sin can be changed into is it a crime?

Of course, in practice there are tons of nuance. Things like smoking ganja in some states in US. Is it legal? There is no clear answer. The same way is something legal in ancient israel may vary from kings to kings and enforceable differently

Comment: This isn't about Christianity, so doesn't seem on topic here. It might be a better fit for our [Judaism site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It could be relevant because then questions like is it a sin can be changed into is it a crime?

Comment: @Korosia I'm hesitant to migrate this question there, worded as it is.  There's no reason Christians can't comment on the Old Testament, the OP just has to realize they're going to get a Christian exegetical  answer instead of an answer from a Jewish historian.  Could also go to history.SE for answer.

Comment: For the record money laundering is a sin, gambling often is a sin, porn can (and should) be criminal and fornication is often illegal too.  [Adultery is illegal in Wisconsin](https://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/statutes/statutes/944/III/16)

Comment: @user, I closed your question so you can edit it to be more specific.  If you want to ask on Judaism instead, that's probably acceptable, but they have a fairly high standards for questions.  I think history.SE might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

While the Jewish Law from the Old Testament may focus on sins that result in actions that can be observed, investigated, and prosecuted by the state, i.e., crimes, it has also always said that there are thoughts that are sinful too. One of the most prominent examples of these is the last of the Ten Commandments: do not covet your neighbour's wife or property. You don't have to act on lust or greed for it still to be sin and an obstacle between you and God.

Answer (score 0):

Sin is viewed somewhat differently in Judaism than in Christianity. Judaism regards the violation of any of the [613 commandments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/613_commandments) as a sin, anything not in these commandments is not. Judaism teaches that to sin is a part of life, since there is no perfect man and everyone has an inclination to do evil "from his youth".

Unlike Christianity, sins committed out of lack of knowledge are not considered sins, since a sin can't be a sin if the one who did it didn't know it was wrong. Unintentional sins are considered less severe sins. This is in contrast to Christianity's view that all people are sinners, as expressed in Romans 3:23:

> for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God

Also unlike Christianity, sins between people are considered much more severe in Judaism than sins between man and God. Yom Kippur, the main day of repentance in Judaism, can atone for sins between man and God, but not for sins between man and his fellow, that is until he has appeased his friend.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between "lack of knowledge" sins and "unintentional" sins?

Comment: That second paragraph really mixes up things and is not common theology across all Christianity.  It certainly isn't true according to the Catholic theology.

Comment: "All manner of sin and blasphemy shall be forgiven unto men; but the blasphemy against the Holy Spirit shall not be forgiven unto men" Mat 12:31

Comment: "Unlike Christianity, sins committed out of lack of knowledge are not considered sins, since a sin can't be a sin if the one who did it didn't know it was wrong." This isn't true. Jewish law discusses unintentional sins in great detail, and they certainly require atonement, though the punishment is less severe than for intentional sins. For example, violating the Sabbath unintentionally causes one to be obligated to bring a sacrifice for atonement.

Comment: Unintentional is not the same as lack of knowledge. Missing the Sabbath if you know it's function because you're sick is not the same as missing it because you haven't been taught.

Comment: @Codosaur I agree that those are not the same, but they're both discussed and the required atonement for both of them is a "chatat" sacrifice.